# Why does this function returns only the expected output when I log the elements to the console in the if/else statement

Tags: javascript, filter

Why does this function returns only the expected output when I log the elements to the console in the if/else statement, and not when I use a return statement, and console.log the function invocation?

```
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function checkAdult(age) {
 for( let el of age){
    if(el >= 18){
    console.log(el);    
    }
  }
}
checkAdult(ages);  // expected [32, 33, 40] 


var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function checkAdult(age) {
 for( let el of age){
    if(el >= 18){
      return el;    
     }
   }
 }
console.log(checkAdult(ages));  // 32 ??
```

Comment: Because `return` stops execution of the function.  The first version just runs until it's checked all elements.

Comment: Of course, thanks Archer!